# How to line up image of <li></li> with its text when the image used for the bullet point is greatter than 16*16?

Tags: css, html-lists, point

Here is my code for `<li>` style.

```css
li{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 color: black;
 display : list-item;
 list-style-image : url('img/bulletpoint_resoltion_32px.png'); //
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First text</li>
  <li>Seond text</li>
</ul>
```

Anyone knows how to line up image with text into li? (instead of these dots, these dots are replaced by image which does not line up with the text

Comment: Can you supply an example of what you are trying to get ?

Comment: if your image is 32px square then the minimum height of your li will need to match it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your list items in a `span` tag and then use the style `vertical-align: 'n' px;` for this tag.

For e.g. if your 'bullet image' has a size of 64*64px the value of n will be 24 (if font-size is 100%

i.e `(64(image height) - 16(font-size)) / 2` ). A bit of math there.

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li><span>First text</span></li>
   <li><span>Seond text</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: black;
    display : list-item;
    list-style-image : url('http://freedomdefined.org/upload/thumb/5/5c/Fd_sq_icon_sc.svg/64px-Fd_sq_icon_sc.svg.png');
}
span{
    vertical-align: 24px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/on6rqm2u/).

Comment: In stackoverflow you thank someone who solves your problem by upvoting the answer. Please do so if it really helped you. Make sure you do so in every such situations! :)

Comment: I tryed to up vote you but stackoverflow told me that i must have 15 reputation to do so. I only have Reputation = 1 :'(

Comment: Haha! That's okay... you'll learn coding with practice.. then you'll have much higher reputation! :D

Comment: waiting for this, you may up vote my question, then i'll have reputation = 2 :D

Comment: Fine! U are kind. You answered my question, and you also up vote me. When i'll have 15, i'll come back here to upvote u x) see you @theScorpion

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the list-style image css property. I would use the background url with a class on the  and play with the padding.

```
background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85602335/bulletpoint_resoltion_32px.png') no-repeat left top;
padding: 8px 0px 3px 35px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmarq423/0t2h8por/1/

Comment: I'm going to try this too